# Responsive full-width Wordpress post image

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site and the images in my posts force the width of my site, breaking it when it's mobile sized. Looking for code to make the Wordpress post images full width (with auto height to maintain proportions) based on container size.

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="container">

            <?php the_content();?>

</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

EDIT

```
function theme_content_image_sizes_attr( $sizes, $size ) {
$width = $size[0];

if ( 740 <= $width ) {
    $sizes = '(max-width: 706px) 89vw, (max-width: 767px) 82vw, 740px';
}

return $sizes;
}
add_filter( 'wp_calculate_image_sizes', 'theme_content_image_sizes_attr', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: You can have the images change size depending on the browser width using `@media` rule in `css`. If you research  `@media` I am sure you will be able to write a solution.

Comment: I'm not looking for a change size as you are correct, writting a code for the image size based on @media. But I'm looking for full width images regardless of width. The images would not have a set size

Comment: So you want the images to scale/fit the screen width? Can you show the `css` you are currently using for the images in question. Thank you.

Comment: I am trying to alter the code from similar themes as edited. Just not sure how. I am not attached to this method if there is a better way.

Comment: Essentially what is hapening is my images are currently brought in at a certain size. As the window scales down, the images stay a certain size and keep the width of the site at their width. (which creates a horizontal scroll bar on mobile). I want them to have a responsive full width so they are as large as they can be, but not change the website width

Comment: Well your attempt looks very much like this article [**Controlling Responsive Image Sizes in WordPress**](https://pineco.de/controlling-responsive-image-sizes-in-wordpress/) Maybe you can find something like a related post on there to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion, maybe you can use the featured image as a background so you can control the width and height.

```
<?php $backgroundImg = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' ); ?>

<div class="header-wrap" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $backgroundImg[0]; ?>')">
</div>

.header-wrap {
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
   padding: 80px 0;
}
```

Comment: It's a great suggestion, and I do use the feature image in a similar way. I am referring to the images that are put into the post itself ( mixed in with the text)

Comment: okay, can you add these styles to your content images

`img {
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 100%;
   display: block;
}` but i guess it still depends on the actual image size